# SQLite 3 for iOS with EF Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, entity-framework-core

I am currently working on a Xamarin project using a SQLite database. We are creating views using ExecuteSqlCommand and in one of these views I need to use ROW_NUMBER, which is only supported in SQLite3.

This is fine for UWP and Android as the 'SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green' NuGet package (Which 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' uses) supports SQLite 3, but iOS is different and doesn't support SQLite3 by default.

In the NuGet package for 'SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green' it does say "Policy of this bundle: iOS=system SQLite, others=e_sqlite3 included". It also talks about how it uses the same configuration on everything except iOS so that explains why iOS is the only platform with this issue.

I tried adding a couple of the providers for SQLite to get it to support a later version but wasn't having any success. I assume there must be some way to change this for iOS but searching for information on "iOS=system SQLite" just beings up the SQLite home page and a bunch of unrelated pages.

I can change the query to not use SQLite 3, but it feels stupid to support SQLite3 on the other 2 platforms but not be able to use it because of iOS.

Is there some NuGet Package that I can add to the iOS project so that we can use SQLite3 queries?

Comment: Install the `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3` and call `SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();` to init it (all platforms)

Comment: @SushiHangover I've added the bundle to the iOS project and changed the init to be Batteries_V2 instead of just Batteries, but this causes a JIT error because iOS is AOT-only. Happens when it tries to open the connection in EnsureCreated. I assume this is because it's trying to load a DLL when opening the connection? I tried adding each of the SQLitePCLRaw packages manually instead of the package but same issue. I also tried adding the ios_unified package and calling SetProvider like is says but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I know EFCore has had issues w/ iOS AOT requirement (was it fixed?) and that is just one of the reasons that I do not use it on mobile. Also I do not know of anything in the SQLitePCLXXX bundles that are emitting IL that would cause an iOS fault.

Comment: @SushiHangover Unfortunately looks like we're all up to date on EFCore stuff. Would have to go to EFCore 3, but we can't do that because of Xamarin. So I guess that means we're out of luck and just wont be able to use SQLite3 features on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

In your iOS AppDelegate:  Before you call

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
```

you need to call:

```
SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();
```

Also, you need to set the following somewhere, it's an attribute and can be set almost anywhere:

```
[assembly: Preserve(typeof(System.Linq.Queryable), AllMembers = true)]
```

AND you cannot use DynamicProxy. All of this is due to AOT, I am not going to explain any of this, it is all in other answers.